# Getting a list of cast-capable devices

Tags: android, google-cast

In Android, is there any way to discover and get a list of devices that are cast-capable without having the user go through the MediaRouteButton?

Comment: For instance, if I was in a service or broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChromeCast devices are DIAL servers: http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-protocol-specification

You can discover their broadcasts on the network and determine their capabilities. You can do all of this in a service. I have written a DIAL client in Android that you could try: https://github.com/entertailion/DIAL

Google TV devices are also DIAL servers, so you would have to distinguish between those and the ChromeCast devices.

Comment: Interesting, has there been any work to inject a Cast compatible DIAL API into Chrome or Firefox through an extension?